# connecting to exposed docker container

Tags: docker

I'm trying to expose a docker container to the outside world, not just the host machine.  When I created the image from a base CentOS image it looks like this:

```
# install openssh server and ssh client
RUN yum install -y openssh-server
RUN yum install -y openssh-clients

RUN echo 'root:password' | chpasswd

RUN sed -ri 's/UsePAM yes/#UsePAM yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -ri 's/#UsePAM no/UsePAM no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

I run this image like so:

```
sudo docker run -d -P crystal/ssh
```

When I try to look at the container with `sudo docker ps`, I see Ports:

```
0.0.0.0:49154->22tcp
```

If I `ifconfig` on the host machine (ubuntu), I see docker0 inet addr:172.17.42.1.  I can ping this from my host machine, but not from any other machine.  What am I doing wrong in setting up the container to look at the outside world?  Thanks.

Edit:

I have tried inspecting the IPAddress of the container and I see IPAddress: 172.17.0.28, but I cannot ping that either...

If I try nmap , that seems to return the ports.  So does that mean it is open and I should be able to ssh into it if I have ssh set up?  Thanks.

nmap -p 49154 10.211.55.1 shows that the port is open with an unknown service.

I tried to ssh in by ssh -l root -p 49154 10.211.55.1 and I get

```
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer.
```

Comment: Have you tried to connect to public ip address of host machine on port 49154? I mean IP address of eth0 interface?

Comment: @Jiri I tried `nmap -p 49154 <eth0 ip>` and that returned: `49155/tcp, open, service unknown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Your Dockerfile is wrong. Your sshd is not properly configured, it does not start properly and thats the reason while container does not respond on port 22 correctly. See errors:

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

You need to generate host keys. This line will do the magic:

```
RUN ssh-keygen -P "" -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

You probably need to look up IP address of eth0 interface (that is accessible from network) and you need to connect to your container via this IP address. Traffic from/to `docker0` bridge should be forwarded by default to your eth interfaces.

Also, you better check if you have ip forwarding enabled:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

This command should return 1, otherwise you should execute:

```
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Q: Why you can connect this way to container?

If you have ip forwarding enabled, packets incoming from eth0 interface are forwarded to virtual docker0 interface. Magic happens and packet is received at correct container. See [Docker Advanced Networking](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/) for more details:

> But `docker0` is no ordinary interface. It is a virtual Ethernet bridge
>   that automatically forwards packets between any other network
>   interfaces that are attached to it. This lets containers communicate
>   both with the host machine and with each other. Every time Docker
>   creates a container, it creates a pair of “peer” interfaces that are
>   like opposite ends of a pipe — a packet sent on one will be received
>   on the other. It gives one of the peers to the container to become its
>   eth0 interface and keeps the other peer, with a unique name like
>   vethAQI2QT, out in the namespace of the host machine. By binding every
>   veth* interface to the docker0 bridge, Docker creates a virtual subnet
>   shared between the host machine and every Docker container.

Comment: how would I connect to the container's ip address from the eth0 address?  let's say docker's ip is 172.17.42.5, and eth0 is 10.211.55.1, then how do I connect from the outside world?  As an aside, I'm trying to ssh in from the docker docs.  (http://docs.docker.io.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/examples/running_ssh_service/).  ip_forward did return 1.

Comment: @Crystal You cannot connect to "containers IP address" from outside, but (only) packets to specific host port at eth0 are forwarded to container specific port. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ping 172.17.42.1 from outside your host because it is a private ip so it can be accessed only in private network as it is the one created by the host on which you run the docker container, the virtual switch docker0 and the docker container which is attached with a virtual interface to the bridge docker0...

Moreover 172.17.42.1 is the ip of the bridge docker0, not the ip of your docker instance. If you want to know the ip of the docker instance you have to run ifconfig inside it or you can use `docker inspect`

I'm not an expert about port mapping, but up to me that means that to access the docker container on port 22 you have to connect to port 49154 of the host and all the traffic will be forwarded.

Comment: I updated my question, but I have tried to ping the ip from the `inspect` command and I continue to get Request timeout.

Comment: From the outside you will always get Request timeout for ping because it is a private address. If you run another docker container, each docker can ping the other, but no host can ping them from outside. Up to the `ssh` command I think that Jiri's answer may be the solution.